# Can the shape of the clickable area of an HTML anchor tag be changed?

Tags: html, css, anchor, shapes, geometry

I've been working on a site with a large circular logo in the header. The logo is an anchor tag set up as follows:

```
<a id="siteLogo" href="#" shape="circle" coords="157,155,147"><i>Site Logo</i></a>
```

Relevant CSS follows:

```
i { 
   visibility: hidden; }
#siteLogo {
   background-image: url(../imgs/sprites_main2.png);
   background-position: 1000px 1000px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 100%;
   display: block;
   height: 294px;
   left: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: 8px;
   width: 294px; }
#siteLogo:hover {
   background-position: -15px -324px; }
```

Setting the `shape` and `coords` attributes on the anchor tag will give me a link with a circular clickable (opposed to the normal square) area in Opera and Firefox. Chrome, Safari, and IE do not support theses attributes on anchor tags. I did some checking and it seems that HTML5 also does not support these attributes (correct me if I am wrong).

The question I pose to the community is simple. Is there anyway I can achieve a similar result as above that is HTML5 compliant and supported by the major browsers (I can live without IE support) without using an image map or adding any image tags to my HTML?

Javascript or jQuery solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Old school image map + JS maybe? Still supported as far as I know.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Actually, I think just an image map will suffice. What would you need the JS for?

Comment: IDK, last time I did image map coding it was the 90s.

Comment: Yes, an image map would work. I would really rather just not use one. I was hoping maybe someone had some magical way of doing this cross browser without the image map.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using padding property to increase the size of clickable area..

Comment: It's not the size of the clickable area that is my issue, I am looking for a way to make it a circle rather than a square. You can achieve that in Opera and Firefox, just not in any of the other browsers and it seems that HTML5 doesn't support using shape or coords on an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but you can use a `<div>`, etc, with rounded corners. E.g.

```
<div style="border-radius:50px; border:1px solid black; 
  width:100px; height:100px;"  
  onclick="merry_go()">Stuff goes here</div>
```

gets you a 100px circle.